# how to achieve this DIVs(HTML) layout in the screen

Tags: css, layout, html

hello all am looking for the best way to organize DIVs(HTML)
in screen what am looking for is something like that

```
DIV(100% height  align left)         DIV(50% height align right)  
                                     DIV(50% height align right)
```

i want to use only DIVs
i already did it using tables and it is working but wondered if i can do it using DIVs
one hint that i used is the float=left.

thanks for all the help

Comment: 100% and 50% of a fixed height parent, of the viewport or of the whole page?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Where is your HTML and CSS? If you expect an answer, you need to ask a real and specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest one - http://jsfiddle.net/JeHfy/13/

```
<div class="col1">
  column 01
</div>
<div class="col2">
   column 02   
</div>
<div class="col3">
  column 03    
</div>

html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.col1{
width:50%;
height:100%;
background:#666;
float:left;
}

.col2, .col3{
width:50%;
height:50%;
background:#333;
float:left;
}
.col3{
background:#999; 
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a number of things, do you want the content to spread across the whole page or do you want it to be a fixed width?

I have found that using 100% height rarely works in HTML, the height will be dependent on the content of the DIV unless you specify a height in px and set the overflow.

IF you are looking for grid layouts check out http://960.gs/ it makes grid layout quick and easy to write and gives you a fixed 960px page. It should take no more than 20-30 minutes to get the hang of and there are plenty of examples on the internet.

We used the grid960 layout for one of our websites at work http://www.matchtech.com

Comment: `height: 100%;` is not as mysterious as you're saying. If a height is specified in percentage, it will be determined based on the parent element's specified height. If the parent element's height is set to auto, no measurement can really take place.